# how to install dnn (v 5.2.0) in vs (any of 2005 or 2008)?

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

i need to install DNN on my pc. I dont mind what dotnet version this would be: either 2005 or 2008 but i need to install DNN v 5.x.y and not any previous installation + also need to configure in my sql server (could be 2005 or 2008)

Please suggest me some correct steps

thanks.

Comment: there are some 'views' but no solution... i expect some good input to come out here.!!!

Comment: Are you trying to create a website to use for developing modules in Visual Studio?  Or some other scenario?

Comment: yes i am creating website in which i would develop my own module or may be i could customize the existing module too

Answer (score 1):

Fastest easiest way might be to download the [Visual Studio Starter kit from CodePlex](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=36408)  and install it:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Select `Create Web Site`
3. Select `DotNetNuke Web Application Framework` from `My Templates`
4. Set the location to put it in then let it go

then run the website and violà you have a simple local install. Mess with it from there, but that should get you going.